# Slow initial http requests with spring in k8s

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes

I have a simple java app with a controller that simply returns a hello world jsp. It works as expected deploying in a non-k8s environment, however when deploying on k8s it takes about 15 seconds to respond the first time the page is requested. After the first request, performance is back to normal responding in a split second. I've enabled debug logs for spring but nothing much useful there, just 15 seconds of no logs:

```
2021-08-04 16:38:16,856 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/jsp/test.jsp]
...
2021-08-04 16:38:31,452 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter: Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5073a20b
2021-08-04 16:38:31,453 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper: SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2021-08-04 16:38:31,455 DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor: Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2021-08-04 16:38:31,459 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet: Completed 200 OK
2021-08-04 16:38:31,459 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter: Chain processed normally
2021-08-04 16:38:31,460 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter: SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I was wondering if anyone has any advice on what might be going on, or how I could investigate further?

Comment: Hard to say why you're only seeing this in a K8S deployment.  I suspect in your non-K8S environment your application get's warmed up before accepting requests (just guessing).  Anyway, you could configure your container with a readinessProbe to make an initial request.  This would insure that your users never have to experience this delay on initial requests.

Comment: It could be the case that you have your cache setup on a network file store, which could introduce slowness. try disabling response caching and see if it helps.

Comment: Is you app getting throttled by k8s? There is a high chance that on the first request several pools (threads, db connections) are created and your applications need more resources during the warm up phase. Depending on your limits the app gets throttled and therefore slower in k8s compared to non-k8s env. Check k8s metrics, e.g. cpu, cpu throttling, number of threads, memory and other jvm/stack related metrics.

Comment: Please show the deployment/replicaset/pod yaml and loadbalancer/ingress configuration

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with using **redhat openshift container platform**, **helm** and a **spring boot application**.

My start up time until the spring application is ready is up to 90 seconds in the ocp (=openshift container platform). On my local machine the application starts within 5 seconds.

Also when i make my first request the response time is between 5 - 15 seconds and after that around 100ms - 300ms. I have no idea why it takes so long on the first request. I'm also using keycloak and on the first request it maybe takes that long, because you have to get the keycloak access token, but that shouldn't take that long, or should it?